# 16.04 LTS, `php -v` in console shows PHP 7.0.33, but PHP 7.3 *is* installed, however I can't use Composer since it needs PHP 7.2+

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php, php7

I'm trying to install something with Composer and am told I need PHP 7.2+. I know for a fact that PHP 7.3.22 is installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS/Apache2/Plesk 18 system as reported by `phpinfo();` and in my Plesk panel.  However, when in console, if I execute `php -v`, it says PHP 7.0.33 is installed and also Composer complains that it needs PHP 7.2+.

I attempted to upgrade PHP, but it can never find the PHP packages. Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 1):

you need to execute:

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

it will show you all your versions of PHP and the selected. Only type the number of the optiont that match with the version and press Intro.

The output of `update-alternatives` is similar to this:

```
  Selecction   Route            Priority   State
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        auto
  1            /usr/bin/php5.6   56        manual
  2            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        manual
* 3            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        manual
  4            /usr/bin/php7.3   73        manual
  5            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        manual
```

For `PHP 7.3`, the number is 4 in this case.